# rails console error require './example_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the railstutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec:a_user_class

I've been told to type require `'./example_user'` but... I get this error

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- example_user
from /Users/snook3/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require'
```

and then further and further errors

I imagine that I'm not linking correctly to that folder, can anyone let me know where I should be linking too?

Comment: Did you put the example_user.rb file in the project root? Are you requiring it after you run `rails c`? If so, it should work

Comment: and that was the problem. Cheers! I thought RVM was ruining everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just move the file to the actual root directoy. Doing `mv example_user.rb* /` should do it.

Also, don't worry if after requiring the file, you get a return of "true" instead of ["User"].

Answer (score 1):

You can use
    `Rails.root` 
to get your current Rails project root.

So 
`require Rails.root + 'path_to_example_user'`

would load the file.

You can also try the `reload!` command, which will reload the whole Rails environment.

Answer (score 1):

The file should end with `.rb`:

```
    require './example_user'    #will not work
    require  './example_user.rb'      #will work
```

To rename the file, use the following command line (not in the rails console):

```
    mv example_user example_user.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

try using absolute path for the file... something like this:

```
require '/Users/snook3/my/project/folder/example_user.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify the full path, simply append *.rb* to the filename: `require './example_user.rb'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, but not being very familiar with Unix I can only explain it like this.

1) I created the example_user.rb file in Sublime Text 2 and saved it to the application root folder.

2) The "require" wasn't working for me, just like the OP. Even though I could see the file there in the folder.

3) However, opening up a Terminal window, navigating to the application root, and entering "dir", I could then see that the filename had a "/ " before it!? Not sure how/why that happened, or why it wasn't visible in Explorer (or whatever the Unix equivalent of that is called--Nautilus?).

4) After renaming the file from within Terminal, it all worked. But would love an explanation of what went wrong if this makes sense to any of you Unix/Rails folks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
touch example_user.rb
```

in Unix terminal. And then add code to this file.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial tells you to "create the file example_user.rb in your application root directory".  I mistakenly initially put it in the app folder and got the same error message.

If you instead move the file into your project root directory, then `require './example_user'` will work.