# " require './example_user' " results in " LoadError: no such file to load -- ./example_user "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Hartl's tutorial. 
The instructions say to "create the file `example_user.rb` in your application root directory". I'm assuming that's just under `rails_projects/sample_app`. I then start the console and type

```
require './example_user'
```

but get the error message

```
`LoadError: no such file to load -- ./example_user`.
```

Another answer said that you have to use the mv function to move the file to the actual root directory, but I was unable to make sense of that. Is the root directory not simply in `sample_app`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your console: try `Dir.pwd`, what it print?

Comment: It says ""/Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app""

Comment: That says "["app", "config", "config.ru", "db", "doc", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "Guardfile", "lib", "log", "public", "Rakefile", "README.md", "script", "spec", "test", "tmp", "vendor"]"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11818634/1581531 you need move the file.

Comment: I don't understand "[code]mv example_user.rb* /[/code]" What is "code" and what is actually happening?

Comment: [code] is only `tag` for markdown http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: It's not working for me. I typed "mv example_user.rb*" and then I typed "require './example_user'" and I still get errors. Can you please tell me what to type in the terminal?

Comment: My guess is you created the file "example_user.rb" somewhere else accidentally...make sure the file /Users/marlon/rails_projects/sample_app/example_user.rb exists and is the one you're editing...

Comment: ^Thanks, it was my stupid mistake. I put it in the app subfolder before.

Comment: This post would help!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616722/rails-console-error-require-example-user